# Erlang application exit,, but vm is still running

Tags: erlang

My Erlang applicaation processed crashed and then exited, but found that the erlang VM is still running.
I could recieve `pong` when ping this "suspended node"

Types `regs()` and the results show below, there is not my app process.

```
(hub@192.168.1.140)4> regs().

** Registered procs on node 'hub@192.168.1.140' **
Name                  Pid          Initial Call                      Reds Msgs
application_controlle <0.7.0>      erlang:apply/2                30258442 1390
auth                  <0.20.0>     auth:init/1                        189    0
code_server           <0.26.0>     erlang:apply/2                 1194028    0
erl_epmd              <0.19.0>     erl_epmd:init/1                    138    0
erl_prim_loader       <0.3.0>      erlang:apply/2                 2914236    0
error_logger          <0.6.0>      gen_event:init_it/6           49983527    0
file_server_2         <0.25.0>     file_server:init/1            16185407    0
global_group          <0.24.0>     global_group:init/1                107    0
global_name_server    <0.13.0>     global:init/1                     1385    0
gr_counter_sup        <0.43.0>     supervisor:gr_counter_sup          253    0
gr_lager_default_trac <0.70.0>     gr_counter:init/1                  121    0
gr_lager_default_trac <0.72.0>     gr_manager:init/1                   46    0
gr_lager_default_trac <0.69.0>     gr_param:init/1                    117    0
gr_lager_default_trac <0.71.0>     gr_manager:init/1                   46    0
gr_manager_sup        <0.45.0>     supervisor:gr_manager_sup          484    0
gr_param_sup          <0.44.0>     supervisor:gr_param_sup/1          253    0
gr_sup                <0.42.0>     supervisor:gr_sup/1                237    0
inet_db               <0.16.0>     inet_db:init/1                     749    0
inet_gethost_native   <0.176.0>    inet_gethost_native:serve      4698517    0
inet_gethost_native_s <0.175.0>    supervisor_bridge:inet_ge           41    0
init                  <0.0.0>      otp_ring0:start/2             30799457    0
kernel_safe_sup       <0.35.0>     supervisor:kernel/1                278    0
kernel_sup            <0.11.0>     supervisor:kernel/1              47618    0
lager_crash_log       <0.52.0>     lager_crash_log:init/1        97712230    0
lager_event           <0.50.0>     gen_event:init_it/6         1813660437    0
lager_handler_watcher <0.51.0>     supervisor:lager_handler_          358    0
lager_sup             <0.49.0>     supervisor:lager_sup/1             327    0
net_kernel            <0.21.0>     net_kernel:init/1            110769667    0
net_sup               <0.18.0>     supervisor:erl_distributi          313    0
os_cmd_port_creator   <0.582.0>    erlang:apply/2                      81    0
rex                   <0.12.0>     rpc:init/1                    15653480    0
standard_error        <0.28.0>     erlang:apply/2                       9    0
standard_error_sup    <0.27.0>     supervisor_bridge:standar           41    0
timer_server          <0.100.0>    timer:init/1                  59356077    0
user                  <0.31.0>     group:server/3                23837008    0
user_drv              <0.30.0>     user_drv:server/2             12239455    0

** Registered ports on node 'hub@192.168.1.140' **
Name                  Id              Command
ok
```

It rarely occurs, but anyone explains it?

> System: CentOS 5.8
>
> Erlang: R15B03

Comment: If your processes belong to an Erlang application, you could try to see if it is started by finding it in the results of `application:which_applications()`. If it is running, you might have a broken supervisor structure that doesn't restart your processes.

Comment: Yes my app is Erlang app. But I'm so sorry to that I made mistake to kill that process. Now I cann't reproduce it...